# What is the proper way to parse yahoo currency http://finance.yahoo.com/connection/currency-converter-cache?date?

Tags: php, json, parsing, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

As the code i tried and by trial removal to get json content out of the return is below 
method i used.

```
$date= YYYYMMDD; 

//example '20140113'

$handle = fopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/connection/currency-converter-cache?date='.$date.'', 'r');

//sample code is http://finance.yahoo.com/connection/currency-converter-cache?date=20140208 paste the url in browser;

// use loop to get all until end of content 

   while (!feof($handle)) {
            $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
        }
        fclose($handle);
```

the code return a given bulk in yahoo and json format

so remove the unknown format which is

```
   "/**/YAHOO.Finance.CurrencyConverter.addConversionRates (" and ends with ");"
```

by

```
  $contents = str_replace('/**/YAHOO.Finance.CurrencyConverter.addConversionRates(','',$contents);
        $contents = str_replace(');','',$contents);
        $obj = json_decode($contents,true);


then loop the content by 
foreach($obj['list']['resources'] as $key0 => $value0){

}
```

Comment: This endpoint is designed to be used with javascript. The "unknown format" you speak of is the callback function that is called when this endpoint is hit and you're using their framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use `file_get_contents` to get the `html` and `preg_match_all` to cleanup the `json`, i.e.:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("http://finance.yahoo.com/connection/currency-converter-cache?date=20140113");
preg_match_all('/\((.*)\);/si', $json, $json, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$json =  $json[1][0];
$json = json_decode($json,true);

foreach ($json["list"]["resources"] as $resource){
    echo $resource["resource"]["fields"]["date"];
    echo $resource["resource"]["fields"]["price"];
    echo $resource["resource"]["fields"]["symbol"];
    echo $resource["resource"]["fields"]["price"];
}
```

---

**NOTE:**

I've tested the code and it works as intended.